# How do I add a non-exposed field to node programatically?

Tags: 7, entities

I need to add a non-exposed field to a node programatically. By non-exposed, I mean a field which users will not be able to interact with. I need to be able to store data in this field through hook_folder_form().

There's always the accepted answer to [Add field in hook_node_info();](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32375/add-field-in-hook-node-info), but that seems to imply that we're talking about exposed fields.

Comment: You can add a cck field like other fields and restrict the visibility of field by using content access permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can add field via structure->content types-> manage fields in your content type, add field that you want to hide.

to hide field in a edit-form/node you can use

```
function yourmodulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if (!empty($form['type']['#value']) && $form['type']['#value'] == 'formtypename') {
hide($form['fieldmachinname']);
]
```